# ng repeat data member acces in controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to acces data member of ng-repeat like `s.sessionyear` in controller using `$scope` or by using any other methhod i want to acces `s.sessionyear` in controller my html file is

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in sessions" >
                <td>{{s.id}}</td>
                <td>{{s.sessionyear}}</td>
                <td><a ng-href="#/session/{{s.id}}/edit">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a ng-href="#/session/{{s.id}}/delete" >Delete</a></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" ng-model="sessionyear" value="s.sessionyear"/>
                </td>   
        <td><div ng-repeat="t in terms">{{t.termtitle}}</div></td>

            </tr>
```

controller is

```
firstApp.controller('sessionsCtrl', function ($scope, sessionSvc,termSvc) {
$scope.sessions = sessionSvc.readData().query();


alert("alert working"+$scope.sessionyear);

$scope.terms=termSvc.readData().query();
}

);
```

Comment: So you need to _loop_ over `$scope.sessions`, some sort of `$scope.sessions[0].sessionyear`? Because the `alert` makes no sense. `$scope.sessions` is an array. There's more than one `sessionyear` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in the controller which accepts  sessionyear as an argument, alert your data in this function. 
Call this function from inside the repeater using {{}} from any of the td tags

Comment: please give me more hints

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in Controller like:

```
$scope.getSessionYear = function(sessionYear)
{
     console.log("sessionYear::::"+sessionYear);
     alert(sessionYear);
};
```

You can call this function from template like :

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in sessions">
    <td>{{s.id}}</td>
    <td>{{s.sessionyear}}</td>
    <td><a ng-href="#/session/{{s.id}}/edit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a ng-href="#/session/{{s.id}}/delete">Delete</a></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" ng-model="sessionyear"
               value="s.sessionyear" />{{getSessionYear(s.sessionyear)}}</td>
    <td><div ng-repeat="t in terms">{{t.termtitle}}</div></td>
</tr>
```

This way you can retrieve the `sessionYear` value in your controller for each sessions array element.

Thanks.